# Reading file descriptor size from popen command for socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have seen similar questions asked but I seek a more specific way of how to correctly do it. I am creating a client and a server UDP FTP service where the client has options of

- get [file_name]
- put [file_name]
- delete [file_name]
- ls
- exit

Currently, all implementations work except for my ls as I am trying to ensure the contents of "ls" are less than my buffer size so I know whether to receive/send continually. From what I have learned with research, I am getting an error because you cannot do `ftell` on a `popen` file descriptor given it is a pipe rather than the full contents of the `popen` command. Looking for help on how my implementation should be changed (mainly with doing `ls -l` on the server and sending the contents of it to the client).

My current code is as follows

```
FILE *fp=popen("ls -l","r");  
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
      long numbytes = ftell(fp);
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);    
      char tmp[SO_SNDBUF];
      sprintf(tmp, "%d", numbytes); 
      n = sendto(sockfd, tmp, strlen(tmp), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen); //send ls file size
      if (n < 0) 
        error("ERROR in sendto");  
      if(numbytes<SO_SNDBUF)
      {
        bzero(buf, SO_SNDBUF);
        fread(buf, sizeof(char), numbytes, fp);
        n = sendto(sockfd, buf, numbytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen);
        if (n < 0) 
          error("ERROR in sendto");
      }
      else
      {
        //outgoing file is larger than buffer size
        long totalSent = 0;
        while(totalSent<numbytes)
        {
          bzero(buf, SO_SNDBUF);
          if((numbytes-totalSent)<SO_SNDBUF)
          {
            fread(buf, sizeof(char), numbytes-totalSent, fp);
            n = sendto(sockfd, buf, numbytes-totalSent, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen); //send ls contents
            if (n < 0) 
              error("ERROR in sendto");
          }
          else
          {
            fread(buf, sizeof(char), SO_SNDBUF, fp);
            n = sendto(sockfd, buf, SO_SNDBUF, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, clientlen); //send ls contents
            if (n < 0) 
              error("ERROR in sendto");
          }
          totalSent+=n;
        }
      }
      pclose(fp);
```

The main portion of code that would need modifying is: To correctly get how many bytes `ls -l` is returning

```
FILE *fp=popen("ls -l","r");  
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
      long numbytes = ftell(fp);
      fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);    
      char tmp[SO_SNDBUF];
      sprintf(tmp, "%d", numbytes);
```

Comment: There's no way to know in advance how much data `ls` will output, since not even `ls` itself knows that until after it has scanned the folder and generated the output.  All you can do is `fread()` the output in chunks that are small enough to fit into your buffer, and keep sending buffer-sized chunks until you've sent all of the data.

Comment: Btw it's an error to ignore the return value of `fread()`, since that value is required to know how many bytes have actually been placed into your buffer (the number of bytes placed into the buffer may be less than the number of bytes you asked for)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Is there another way to perform the `ls` call on my server other than `popen` such that some pointer has all the contents of the `ls` call which I can then perform some type of `sizeof` operation? I am not required to do `popen` to perform the command on the server side but from researching, that seemed like the best option for executing a shell command

Comment: @freyfrey01 Check out `getline()` function. If you have `ls` command, you should also have it in C library (it is POSIX, not ISO C). Implementing similar yourself is also a good exercise.

Comment: @hyde using getline on the popen file descriptor until EOF and continuously incrementing "fileSize" until the getline loop in completed and that will give me the number of bytes from the ls command?

Comment: @freyfrey01 one option is to not spawn a child process at all; rather just call `opendir()`, `readdir()` and `closedir()` yourself to read the directory directly and generate your own data to send from that.  Alternatively you could call `popen()` and read the data in as usual, but read into a heap-allocated buffer and call `realloc()` to resize the buffer larger if/when necessary to fit more data, or alternatively allocate more buffers (and make a linked list out of them or something)

Comment: Note that calling `popen()` once to read out the bytes and count them, and then calling `popen()` a second time to fill the buffer, will sort-of work but it has a race condition:  what is more file(s) get added to the directory between those two calls?  Then the data from the second `ls` process will not fit into the buffer allocated based on the number of bytes read from the first `ls` process.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner doing the latter would require my client to know how many bytes are being sent over so it can also reallocate the socket buffer

Comment: @freyfrey01 Actually, I meant `getdelim`, not `getline`. Something like `char *buf=NULL; size_t n=0; ssize_t result = getdelim(&buf, &n, EOF, fp);`  ... writing an answer for you, actually.

Comment: @freyfrey01 you'd re-allocate the buffer to be larger whenever it got close enough to full that the next `fread()` might not fit into the existing buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
system("ls -l > ls.txt");
FILE *fp = fopen("ls.txt", "r");
//...
```

If it is not too much to create a temporary file. The advantage is, that you have your content ready (mainly the size).

The other solution would be (as suggested) to read from popen line by line into an array of strings and calculating the total amount of bytes while doing so. The disadvantage here is memory allocation (but we read it into memory anyway).

Comment: I’m seeming to want to go along the route of reading line by line but want to confirm that I am able to do getline within a while loop of the popes file descriptor and accumulate the strlen of the buffer the lines are being read into?

Comment: According to `man popen`, the return value is a normal (buffered) standard I/O stream in all respects (except file positioning, like `ftell` or `fseek` -> `ESPIPE` error), and `getline` returns the number of characters read (no need for `strlen`). So everything should work as expected.

Comment: Ah ok ok, so I can do something such as while(fileSize += getline(…) != -1){…}? @Erdal

Comment: I am a little confused by your conditional expression, but something like that, yes.

Comment: @Edral with that my mind goes to a more tedious approach of `while(1){linesize= getline(..) if(linesize==-1){break} else {filesize+=linesize}}` (trying to format comments on cellphone)

Comment: Better safe than sorry. What do you think the result of `x += fn() != y` would be? I've made a little test and it doesn't seem to give the expected result (`!=` has a higher precedence than `+=`).

Comment: You could also do the following: while ((res = getline(...)) != -1) { linesize += res; /*...*/ } if (feof(fp)) { puts("eof"); /*eof condition*/ } else { puts(strerror(errno)); /*error condition*/ }

Comment: This is only partial solution. `ls.txt` would need to be created with unique temp file name (which has specific ways of doing it correctly), instead of using a fixed name for it. And then there's the cleanup needed, littering temp folder with temp files isn't nice thing to do, especially on a server which isn't going to be booted often.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to read it all in anyway, you could simply do this, if you are on a platform where `getdelim` exists, which you probably are if you are using `ls` command:

```
FILE *fp = popen("ls -l","r");
char *buf = NULL;
size_t buf_size = 0;
ssize_t result = getdelim(&buf, &buf_size, EOF, fp);
if (result < 0) {
    perror("reading output of popen ls");
    // any other error handling
} else {
    // result contains size of entire ls output
    // buf contains the actual data
    // buf_size is useful only, if you want to re-use buf
}
free(buf); // if buf is NULL, does nothing
```

---

A note about using `getdelim` to get the entire file: If reading an actual file from disk, it may be too large to fit in memory. But here we are reading output of `ls` command, which for any practical purposes can't be that large.

Comment: Perfect solution. Retrieve the contents and corresponding attributes in one go, no need for a physical file nor any memory management.